# sleeping/awaiting command processes due to misconfiguring tomcat+hibernate+database

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, tomcat7, c3p0

I am working on a legacy code and I was asked to find out why there are so many `sleeping /awaiting command` processes in `sql server db`. Most if not all of them have a `program_name = 'jTDS'` , take up a lot of CPU + physical_io and are 10+ days old.

More I was looking into it more I was realizing that it must have something to do with database pooling.

It appears as we have 2 places where we are using db pooling:
•   context.xml 
•   applicationContext.xml
On initial load of application, tomcat reads in web.xml which in turn takes context.xml and it creates a container holding shareable db connection.

web.xml also takes applicationContext.xml for spring context information.

When sessionFactory needs to configure hibernate setting it looks for hibernateProperties.

context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" description="DAPS Database" 
    driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" 
    name="jdbc/vda" user="****" password="*****" 
    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" 
    type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
    jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/dbname;user=sa;password=****;TDS=8.0" />
```

web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>Pooled Database Resource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/vda</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>ja`vax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
 </resource-ref>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- Data Source using C3P0 database connection pooling -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/vda</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Hibernate properties to be used in the Session Factory -->
<bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">4</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">20</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
          <value>model/businessobject/login/User.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I added `maxActive="30" maxIdle="10" maxWait="3000"` to *context.xml* file.

I also added:

```
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">1800</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_periods">30</prop>
```

to applicationContext.xml

It looks like there are 2 places where we are setting c3p0 values. If this is the case do we need both?

Is this where my problem is?
Can anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Having sleeping sessions hanging around in SQL Server is normal for an application that is leveraging connection pooling.  They don't generally cause any issues as long as there are no open transactions in them.  How many are we talking about here?  Are they continually increasing or do they reach a threshold?

Comment: @Pam Lahoud I found 845000 processes on production. They are 10 + days old. And CPU for some is 4000+

Comment: @PamLahoud how do you determine whether a 'transaction is still open'.

Comment: @Asher sorry I just saw this comment! Not sure if it's still helpful, but sys.dm_exec_sessions contains a column open_transaction_count. If it's > 0 there's an open transaction (it's SQL 2012 or later).