# multiple versions of same jar

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, tomcat7, jtds

Does it hurt an application in any way if I have 2 same jars but different version?
I just noticed under `tomcat/webapps/app/WEB-INF/lib`:

```
 1. jtds-1.2.5.jar 
 2. jtds-1.1.jar
```

How do I know which JDBC driver `Tomcat` uses?

I removed `jtds-1.1.jar` and restarted all of the services. I was able to login to my application.

Is it ok to get rid of the old one? 
I asked, but no one can tell me why we kept the old one :/

Could having both jars have anything to do with too many sleeping connections in database, by any chance...?

There are so many other jars in that directory that are like this.... it's not even funny :/

Comment: Yes, having two versions of same will create differences in behaviour of your application. Though how much difference be there is depend upon the differences in claases contained with JARs. Whichever be coming first in your tomcat classpath, will be getting referred and loaded. Hard to predict the order of JARs in a classpath located in same directory.. Though very dirty way, however if possible you may decompile classes from both JARs and compare them to understand the differences.

Comment: Moreover, your question appears a little vague. Do you intend to resolve some issue related to sleeping/leaking connections in database? Are you trying to ask whether the duplicate jars could be one reason? By the way, that should not be.

Comment: yea :/ this is my problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109082/sleeping-awaiting-command-processes-due-to-misconfiguring-tomcathibernatedatab